# Rails3 activerecord hashset customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, hashset

I want to pass hashset to ActiveRecord finder method `Model_name.where({ :key => value })`. This works perfectly, but SQL composed from that uses straight comparison =. Is it possible to customize this and switch to LIKE comparison usage with hashset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:key => value` syntax only works for `=`, `IN`, and `BETWEEN` conditions (depending on whether `value` is atomic, an Array, or a Range). Anything else requires you to pass the SQL as a string:

```
Model.where("key LIKE ?", value)
```